# Can a shell script run by the ENTRYPOINT directive of a Dockerfile have access to the container environment variable set by helm chart?

Tags: docker, shell, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

My container is being built and deployed on the AWS EKS k8s cluster by helm charts, which also sets the environment variable in the container.

In the Dockerfile that is used to build the image, I want to run a init shell script in the ENTRYPOINT directive at the last (which is run at the start of the container) for some initial configurations.

Can the shell script have access to the env variable set by the helm charts in the container so that I can have env-specific branches/conditions in the shell script?

Comment: Yes, it can.  Is there a more specific problem you're running into; do you have a [mcve] demonstrating something that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but keep in mind a Helm Chart (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70941212/6309)) which would *override* the `ENTRYPOINT` you defined in your Dockerfile for building your image.

Other than that, at runtime, the `ENTRYPOINT` script will have access to the environment setup by the package manager (Helm) in charge of executing a `docker run` on your image.